# Lock Master Article when translation in progress

Tags: lightning-knowledge

I am working on Lightning Knowledge. I need to lock the master article when translation is in progress. I am able to do so using `After Update Trigger` and `Approval.Lock()` method. However, the message displayed when we try to edit master article is

> 'The record is currently locked'

Is there any way we can customize this message?